# Handling both Windows and anonymous auth in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have a project in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I want users to be logged in automatically with Windows authentication if possible, and fall back to a login screen if not. If I enable only Windows auth and not anonymous auth, the Windows auth hits my middleware just fine and everything is good. If both Windows and anonymous are enabled, however, my middleware is getting an empty `ClaimsIdentity` instead of the `WindowsIdentity` even if they're logged in via Windows.

From another answer, I found to use the below code to force a Windows auth check:

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

With this I was able to use cookies to force a challenge if it hadn't already been attempted, and to show my login page if it had. The problem now is that browsers throw a built-in login message on that Windows challenge if the user isn't logged in.

Is it possible to accomplish this goal in any better way than what I'm doing now? Users having to click cancel out of that forced popup to get to my login screen is annoying, but if there's no better way then that's what it'll have to be.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I want to do the same thing.  Please let me know